# I am trying to add a condition using the "change" function

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to add a condition for buying, the condition is that the CMF should be higher than previous bar.

The code I'm using now sets the alert also if the previous bar was lower.
I can't seem to understand why.

The code is:

```
len = input(20, minval=1, title="Length")
mas = input(title="Aggregation", defval="SUM", options=["SUM", "EMA", "WMA"])
e = input(10.0, title="Volume Exponent (0-10 reduces & 10+ increases volume effect)")
p = input(false, title="Show in Percentage")
mvs = input(false, "Factor in Price (Money Volume)")
src=input(hlc3, title="Source for price factor")
trl = min(low,close[1]), trh = max(high,close[1]) // 'true range' fixes issues caused by gaps in price
wv = pow(volume,e/10.0)*(mvs ? src : 1)
ad = (trh==trl ? 0 : (2*close-(trh+trl))/tr(true))*wv
cmf = mas=="SUM" ? sum(ad, len)/sum(wv, len) : mas=="EMA" ? ema(ad, len)/ema(wv, len) : mas=="WMA" ? wma(ad, len)/wma(wv, len) : na
cmf_p  = if p
    50*cmf+50
else
    cmf
b = p ? 50 : 0

// CMF condition 
CMFPchg = change( cmf,2)
CMFCOND = CMFPchg >= 0.02
```

Comment: Do you still have the same problem if you do `CMFPchg = cmf - nz(cmf[2])`? Note: You might want to use `abs()` if you want to work with only positive numbers.

Comment: that took care of it ! thank you !